# Lock keyboard from CLI

Tags: keyboard, command-line

I used to use `kextload` and `kextunload` to unlock/lock my keyboard. However, the actual kernel extension changes between MacBook  models, and that can have unexpected results.

For example, if the kext is `AppleUSBTCKeyboard`, both unloading and loading work fine. However, if the kext is `AppleHIDKeyboard` (e.g. MacBook Air), unloading works but loading again does not. This means `kextunload -bundle-id com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard` will disable the keyboard, but then it cannot be reenabled with `kextload` and the machine has to be rebooted.

There are some apps that are still able to do it, like [KeyboardCleanTool](https://www.boastr.net/keyboardcleantool/). I’d prefer a CLI way of doing it, though. If possible (but won’t be picky) using only tools that come with macOS, or an open-source one.

Bonus points if there’s also a way to lock the trackpad, but that is less important.

Comment: Just to be clear, you just want to lock your keyboard and/or trackpad while leaving your screen on.  Correct?

Comment: @Allan Yes, that is correct. But is there a way to do it with turning off the screen (but not the machine or logging out/locking)?

Comment: Just out of curiosity...if you disable the keyboard, how would you re-enable it when you are ready to work again?  After all, the keyboard will be disabled.

Comment: With a timer, as I used to: `kextunload … && sleep 30 && kextload …`. I only need temporary locking, for keyboard cleaning. One could also do it with a script to double click (if not locking the trackpad).

Comment: When I clean my keyboard (Apple BT keyboard), I just turn it off, clean it and turn it back on.  If it's a USB, I just disconnect, clean and reconnect.  Is this not a viable solution?

Comment: @Allan No, because I’m on a MacBook. The internal keyboard is the one I want to disable.

Answer (score -1):

One possibility could be to use [ControllerMate](http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/).

You would have to create a Driver Configuration and map all of the keys to None.  Then there are multiple ways to enable/disable the custom Driver Configuration, but unfortunately CLI is currently not an option.

But CM is very customizable and I'm sure you could come up with something.  For example, using the logic blocks, you could have it disable when you have held down Z for 2 seconds, then hold down P and click the mouse.  Using a delay timer block to wait for 30 seconds but then only re-enable if holding the left shift key down and scrolling the mouse up/down.

Another similar utility that might work is [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements).  It is a complete rewrite of his wonderful [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) app which broke hard with macOS Sierra.  It is still in the early development stages but it might have the functionality you need.

Comment: OP already has a non-CLI way to do this, KeyboardCleanTool, as they stated in the question.