# Keyboard shortcut to lock the keyboard, without locking the screen?

Tags: macos, keyboard, software-recommendation

My cat keeps walking over my keyboard.

Is it possible to [lock the keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267654/lock-keyboard-from-cli) with a keyboard short cut but leave the screen running and all apps visible?

Comment: Also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41439/can-i-lock-my-screen-with-a-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: The accepted solution on that question does lock the screen (sleep, screensaver). That is not what I want. I edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: Aah - kind of like unplugging the keyboard entirely. Or forcing you to answer a captcha or math question to start typing again.

Comment: Yeah like unplugging it. Reactivating via mouse input would suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use KeyboardCleanTool (made by the developer of BetterTouchTool).

It opens the application window with a button you have to press in order to lock/unlock the keyboard.

Download it from [BetterTouchTool.net](https://bettertouchtool.net/releases/KeyboardCleanTool.zip)

[image: Screenshot of KeyboardCleanTool on macOS 10.12]

Comment: Can this be moved out of the way enough or be in the background while watching a movie in full screen? I would try it myself but I am currently on the latest beta.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to turn off a keyboard via shortcut because you would have no way to turn it back on.  The best method to achieve what you are looking for is to *disconnect* the keyboard.

**Wired/USB Keyboards**

To do that, you should use a USB with a "disconnect" or a "power switch" to turn it on/off like the [Sabrent 4 Port Switch](http://radnex.us/sabrent-4-port-usb-30-hub-with-power-switches).  I recommended this for a different [question in which the user needed to "reset" the USB bus](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294944/resetting-the-usb-port-on-a-macbook-pro/295187#295187) to redetect their device; this will work perfectly for you.

[image]

When you want to "lock" your keyboard, just turn off the port.  Turning it back on will automatically reconnect it.

**What about wireless?**

Turn it off.  When you turn it back on, it will automatically reconnect.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a laptop :D